# Delete from aliased table doesn't work (but select does)

Tags: sql-server, alias

I need to delete some rows from a table which are not available in another similar table. I can correctly select the rows to be deleted using this piece of code

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB01].[forward].[forward_value] as DB01
WHERE Id_forward like 'test' and
NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM [DB02].[db_marketdata].[forward].[forward_value] as DB02
    WHERE DB01.Id_Forward = DB02.Id_Forward and
        DB01.Id_Block = DB02.Id_Block and
        DB01.Id_PriceType = DB02.Id_PriceType and
)
```

When I change `SELECT (*)` to `DELETE` I get an error because I can't alias the first table.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

How can I delete those values without using an alias to correctly select the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your alias in `DELETE` syntax like this:

```
delete DB01
FROM [DB01].[forward].[forward_value] as DB01
WHERE Id_forward like 'test' and
NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM [DB02].[db_marketdata].[forward].[forward_value] as DB02
    WHERE DB01.Id_Forward = DB02.Id_Forward and
        DB01.Id_Block = DB02.Id_Block and
        DB01.Id_PriceType = DB02.Id_PriceType 
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, you can use alias like this

```
DELETE DB01
FROM [DB01].[forward].[forward_value] AS DB01
WHERE Id_forward LIKE 'test'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [DB02].[db_marketdata].[forward].[forward_value] AS DB02
        WHERE DB01.Id_Forward = DB02.Id_Forward
            AND DB01.Id_Block = DB02.Id_Block
            AND DB01.Id_PriceType = DB02.Id_PriceType
            AND
        )
```